# Can I make it granted EJB @asynchronous method's thread starts after caller thread ends?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, ejb, ejb-3.1

I wanted to create some process after MDB's onMessage ends.

I think I can realize it using EJB's @asyncronous. But I'm afraid that this method can start before caller thread ends.

Is there any way to make it sure that this asynchronous method start after caller thread ends, at least caller thread commits it's own transaction.

Thanks, and nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using another MDB instead, if you publish a message from within a transaction, the message won't be published until the publisher transaction has been committed:

```
@MessageDriven...
public class MDB1 {

  @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
  public void onMessage(Message message) {
    ...
    producer.send(msg1); // msg1 will be published at commit of this transaction
    ...
    myMethod1();
  }
}
```

and,

```
@MessageDriven... // Consumes msg1
public class MDB2 {

  @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
  public void onMessage(Message message) {
    ...
    myMethod2();
    ...
  }
}
```

this way (and using CMT), the message `msg` won't be published until `MDB1.onMessage()` has returned, and so `MDB2.myMethod2()` will never be executed before `MDB1.onMessage()` returns.

Comment: Ya tambiem ho piensato una vez. Ahora com tua opinion estoy mas confiado de llamar MDB 2 vezes. Gracias.

Comment: Jajaj, bien, Buena Suerte! :) Kōun!